# Change URL shown in Chrome status bar

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-chrome, statusbar

When I hover over a url in Chrome, the url is displayed in the Chrome status bar.  In my case this results in an ugly javascript:bla-bla-bla reference.  Is there any way to change the contents of the status bar when you hover over a link?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure for security reasons this isn't possible in any browser. Otherwise links to phishing sites will become much, much harder to detect, because attackers can then just place a genuine URL in the status bar while the dangerous link actually leads elsewhere...

Use an onclick event handler for your hyperlink instead, and put a real, meaningful URL in the `href` attribute in place of the `javascript:` link (even if the link is meant to be used only with JavaScript).

Comment: I'm developing this to run 'full-screen' in an iPad.  This means that I want to keep using the href="javascript..." format because it is the only one that doesn't 'jump out' of full screen mode.

Comment: @Journeyman: Well in that case I think iOS web app should stay an iOS web app. I'd prefer to serve a different kind of frontend to desktop browsers, with normal hyperlinks instead of the Ajax links that Mobile Safari requires for web apps.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that phishing sites can just add legitimate links and replace their onclick event to lead to a malicious URL?

Comment: @Timo Huovinen: Now that you mention it, yes, they can. I recall seeing a proof of concept demonstrating it somewhere but I can't remember the URL.

Answer (score 10):

Although you selected your answer, this idea is an alternative.

You can change the `href` attribute on `mouseover` to affect what the status bar says, and change it back on `mouseout` or `click`:

```js
function showNiceLink(el, e) {
  e = e || event;
  el.originalHref = el.originalHref || el.href;
  console.log(e.type);

  if (/click|out/i.test(e.type)){
    el.href = el.originalHref;
  } else {
    el.href = "http://Linking...";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#this is a really UGLY link @1##$$%!!&"
   onmouseover="showNiceLink(this,event)"
   onmouseout="showNiceLink(this,event)"
   onclick="showNiceLink(this,event)">a link with an ugly <code>href</code></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onClick="yourFunc(); return false;">Your "link"</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you want to change what destination is shown for link that is selected? In that case you most likely should put nice url in href attribute, and use onclick attribute for your javascript. Not sure that you can duplicate everything what is done by putting javascritp in href.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you have:
`<a onClick="blabla">Link</a>`
Add `href="#"` to it. Then the `#` should be shown in stead of the `javascript:blabla`.
So that would be like this:
`<a href="#" onClick="blabla">Link</a>`

Comment: Do not use `javascript:` in an intrinsic event handler, it will be interpreted as a (useless) label.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot you don't need to add `javascript:` in the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to achieve the desired effect. Just look at what Google puts in the status bar of its search results.

However, you need to use some kind of a trick, e.g. `onclick` like BoltClock suggested.

Google shows you what you would like to see - a plain, clean URL.
Underneath, however, they use a long redirect URL with monitoring parameters to track you down as you click any result link. That way Google monitors which of the search results are clicked on and which are not.

Unfortunately, most people do not realize that. Quite frankly, I would be very glad to see a browser extension which takes all this dirty tricks down and replaces "tracking" URLs with the "real ones".

Comment: My google chrome status bar shows the full real link when I hover over a google search result, is that not what you want the plugin to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the thing I was talking about. I am not sure how it works in Chrome, but Firefox shows just the dummy links (i.e. destinations to where you will be redirected after your click is tracked by Google).

Comment: A browser extension for replacing Google's tracking URLs to search results with the real ones indeed exists: https://github.com/palant/searchlinkfix