# How to mask the url href text with a title

Tags: css, html, anchor

This has got to have already been asked before I cannot find a post for this question.

I have a link with `href="javascript.void(0);"` in it but I don't want to status bar to who this, I'd rather it show some kind of title or an actual url that I want to give it. I tried using the `title` attribute but this doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I've seen this done before so many its been deprecated for `HTML5`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been deprecated due to the security implications, there are features such as window.status which *used* to work, however these no longer seem to be supported by modern browsers.

Previous Similar Questions:

[Change URL shown in Chrome status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394506/change-url-shown-in-chrome-status-bar)

[Change link mouseover text on the bottom of a browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587809/change-link-mouseover-text-on-the-bottom-of-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Ok, it looks like you're trying to change the browser status bar text for a link. using `window.status` to set the display text of a link used to be how this was done, but it is no longer a possibility - it's been turned off in modern browsers for security reasons. However, some sites still do something similar - apparently Facebook and Google, judging from a quick search right here on SO. However, their solutions are a little complicated. I'd suggest going to one of those pages and viewing the source to try to figure it out.

**EDIT #2:** take a look at this jsfiddle - it might do what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/c4BZG/88/

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript.void(0);" 
   onmouseover="showNiceLink(this,event)" 
   onclick="showNiceLink(this,event)" 
   onmouseout="showNiceLink(this,event)">someplace</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function showNiceLink(el,e){
    e = e || event;
    el.originalHref = el.originalHref || el.href;
    console.log(e.type);
    if (/click|out/i.test(e.type)){
        return el.href = el.originalHref;
    } else {
        el.href = "http://Linking...";
    }
}
```