# HTML How to change link text when mouse over

Tags: html, css

When I make a link I do like this `<li><a href="https://www.somePage.net" target="_blank">This is my page</a></li>` But when I hover over the link in Chrome it give away the link I redirect to. Like this [image]

How do I change the text to eg. "My page"

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what u wanna ask?

Comment: At the bottom of the page Chrome writes "https://www.somepage.net" But I want it to write "Redirect to My page" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty sure for security reasons this isn't possible in any browser. Otherwise links to phishing sites will become much, much harder to detect, because attackers can then just place a genuine URL in the status bar while the dangerous link actually leads elsewhere

You can refer to [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394506/change-url-shown-in-chrome-status-bar) for more details

But if you still wanna try this, then go for

scenario as :

```
<a href="#this is a really UGLY link @1##$$%!!&" 
   onmouseover="showNiceLink(this,event)" 
   onclick="showNiceLink(this,event)" 
   onmouseout="showNiceLink(this,event)">someplace</a>
```

And JS

```
function showNiceLink(el,e){
    e = e || event;
    el.originalHref = el.originalHref || el.href;
    console.log(e.type);
    if (/click|out/i.test(e.type)){
        return el.href = el.originalHref;
    } else {
        el.href = "http://Linking...";
    }
}
```

Refer to **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/c4BZG/)**

Comment: okay Thanks, I'll just leave it alone, and stop trying to do it.